# Was Psych the first TV series to remake its own episode?

Tags: first-appearance, psych

Psych, Season 8, Episode 3 ,["Remake A.K.A. Cloudy... With a Chance of Improvement"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psych_%28season_8%29#Episodes), was a remake of the Season 1 Episode ["Cloudy... With a Chance of Murder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psych_(season_1)#ep12).

The wikipedia entry says it is "the first-ever remake episode of the series".

What about other shows? Has any show done it before?

(I'm more curoius about remakes happening within the same series than a remade episode in a remade series.)

Comment: Yup, Psych is the first to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to both IMDb and the USA Network's own website, *Psych* was the first show to remake one of its own episodes.

From IMDb, [Remake A.K.A. Cloudy... With a Chance of Improvement](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3030772/):

> Psych makes television history in a never-been-done remake of the season one episode "Cloudy with a Chance of Murder."

From the "Fun Facts" section of USA Network's [Remake A.K.A. Cloudy…With A Chance Of Improvement](http://www.usanetwork.com/psych/episodes/3-3-7):

> Psych is the first show in the history of television to remake one of their own episodes.